# ¿Cómo evalúo si una cadena contiene una letra específica?

Tags: java

Tengo un código el cual le pide al usuario que ingrese su correo electrónico y a partir de este crear un usuario, he usado un `split` para tomar lo que esta antes del signo `@` y definir que ese sea el usuario por ejemplo si el usuario ingresa `ejemplo123@gmail.com` su usuario será `ejemplo123`, pero no se cómo detectar si el correo que ingresa el usuario contiene contiene el signo `@` y en caso de que no lo contenga envíe el mensaje *correo no valido*

He usado un ciclo `for` para pasar por cada letra del *string* pero la salida que así:

```
Ingresa tu correo electronico

ejemplo123@gmail.com

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Tu usuario es: 

ejemplo123

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

Correo no valido

 ¿sabe como corregir esto?
```

cualquier recomendación o aporte me ayudaría mucho

```
public class Usuario {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingresa tu correo electronico");
        String par = "@";
        String Correo;
        String user;
        Correo = entrada.next();
        char[] caracter = Correo.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<caracter.length;i++) {
            String Vector = String.valueOf(caracter[i]);
            if(par.equals(Vector)) {
                user = Correo.split("@")[0];
                System.out.println("Tu usuario es: ");
                System.out.println(user);

            }else {
                System.out.println("Correo no valido");
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    

}
```

Answer (score 3):

La forma más fácil es [`contains`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_contains.asp)

```java
String ejemplo = "Hola mundo";
System.out.println(ejemplo.contains("mundo")); // true
System.out.println(ejemplo.contains("Hello")); // false
```

Entonces tendríamos

```java
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingresa tu correo electronico");
String correo = entrada.nextLine();
if (correo.contains("@")) {
    String user = correo.split("@")[0];
    System.out.println(user);
} else {
    System.out.println("Correo no válido");
}
```

[Código funcionando](https://onlinegdb.com/2P9beN9am)

---

Normalmente, no se valida un correo con `contains`, [en la mayoría de casos se usan expresiones regulares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204680/java-regex-email)

Tomando la respuesta del post vinculado, tenemos la siguiente expresión regular

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$
```

Entonces, importamos *regex* en nuestro archivo java

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Y validamos la entrada del usuario

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingresa tu correo electronico");
String correo = entrada.nextLine();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(correo);
boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
if(matchFound) {
    String user = correo.split("@")[0];
    System.out.println(user);
} else {
    System.out.println("Correo no válido");
}
```

[Código funcionando](https://onlinegdb.com/aAZQU5ZCt)

Answer (score 1):

*Te comparto una forma viable para el tema de validación de correos usando expresiones regulares*

```
package question_429408;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Usuario {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            String correo = null;
            boolean correoInvalido = true;
            // Definimos la estructura del correo que requerimos
            String formatoCorreo = "([a-z0-9]+(\\.?[a-z0-9])*)+@(([a-z]+)\\.([a-z]+))+";

            // Patron para validar el correo
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(formatoCorreo);

            do {
                // Solicitamos el correo
                System.out.println("Ingresa tu correo electronico");
                correo = entrada.nextLine();

                // Validamos el correo ingresado
                Matcher mather = pattern.matcher(correo);
                // Obtenemos resultado de la validacion cuando es valido se obtiene true, y si no cumple los requisitos retorna false
                //Si retorna false, lo que se hace es realizar el proceso nuevamente
                correoInvalido = !mather.find();

            } while(correoInvalido);

            // Obtener el usuario
            String usuario = correo.split("@")[0];
            System.out.println(usuario);
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            entrada.close();
        }
    }
}
```

*Espero te sirva*